# Triple dispatch design

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, multiple-dispatch

I have a situation similar to the following:

```
class EventHandler { ... }; 
class Event {void Accept(EventHandler&) { ... }};

class SpecialEventHandler : public EventHandler { ... };
class SpecialEvent : public Event {void Accept(SpecialEventHandler&) { ... }};
```

There are some events which are a subtype of `Event` and some which are a subtype of `SpecialEvent`. These events get added to a queue of `Event`s and then I need to handle them with a `SpecialEventHandler`.

The problem is handling the special events as the only the `Accept` method that can be called is the one in `Event` so only an `EventHandler` can be passed in. I have a solution using a double visitor pattern but this is clunky and confusing.

- Is there a pattern for this kind of situation?
- Is there a better way to design it?

Comment: Can you have two different queues?

Comment: That is possible but would add complexity with timing issues to get the order of events right. Also there may be different types of event added in future.

Comment: Add an empty virtual `Accept()` to `Event`, presumably you'll need it anyway for the other `Event` derivees. "I need to call something depending on the class" is best handled by the class itself, across the board.

Comment: The `Event` doesn't know how it should be handled, that depends on the event, handler subclass and the implementation of the handler which is why I see it as triple dispatch.

Comment: I'm not clear on why you need `SpecialEvent`, etc. The Visitor pattern is appropriate in static languages for relatively stable hierarchies, as all the derived types need to be known by the base `Event`. For dynamic, more reflective languages, this restriction is removed.

Comment: The direct subtypes of `Event` are part of the public API and the `SpecialEvent`s are part of the private API which should be hidden.